# multivariate time series analysis with interactions among multiple dependent variables

Tags: time-series, modeling, spatio-temporal

I have been playing with time series data and using models like facebook prophet which uses time series decomposition and models the signal using trend, seasonalities and holidays.

The stuff I found about these time series methods use time as the independent variable and a scalar value as the dependent variable. What about time series models with multiple y-values.

As an example, in my case I am tracking people and I track the counts of people but also the average speed at which they move through a particular section of a shop. Also, there may also be a correlation between these quantities. Are there established time series modelling techniques which can use such multi variate and non independent data sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I fully got your question. But if I did, and you are asking about a multivariate time series, well you have many solutions. Take the following as an introduction more than a fully comprehensive answer.

The models that, among the others, take into account linear interactions between variables that are relevant to their conditional means are [VAR models](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression). Then if you assume that residuals are not independent and there may be some dependencies in the conditional second moments of the series, then you can combine a VAR model for conditional means with a multivariate GARCH allowing you to model dependencies in the conditional second moment [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_heteroskedasticity) for an introduction and then [here](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~rengle/dccfinal.pdf). Then, if you want a very broad and comprehensive specification of a multivariate model, that may include external regressors, constraints, time-varying coefficients etc, in addition to the above mentioned specifications for conditional means and covariances, then see [MARSS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MARSS/vignettes/EMDerivation.pdf)

Comment: Thank you. This got me started.

Comment: You’re welcome Luca, è stato un piacere (my pleasure)!